# Large amount of static values in linked selects! - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a conceptual problem.

For an ASP.NET MVC / C# website (although the exact technology may not be that important) I have 2 linked drop downs (html select) with Countries and Cities of a continent.

These are currently kept in 2 database tables and as you imagine the Cities table has round 10 000 records.

The current functionality is:
- initially the country select is populated. 
- the user selects a country, an ajax request goes to the server, retrieves the cities for that country_id and populates the second (cities) select.

Sometimes it gets a bit slow as you might imagine, and since these are in the end static values (the lists will not change) what will be the best way to treat this situation?

Comment: You could consider caching the data to avoid repeated database calls (e.g. [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: ASP has a specific cache that can be used.. HttpRuntime.Cache

Comment: 10,000 records is not a great many. SQL queries against such a number should take milliseconds. So what is it that is getting "a bit slow"?

Comment: In addition to caching, you should make sure that all of the columns that you are using for joins, where clauses, or order by clauses are indexed. If the tables are properly indexed then 10,000 rows should cause no problems at all. For perspective, I've dealt with tables that contain millions of rows, and with the proper infrastructure, that is totally reasonable

Comment: to be honest problems I've had on mobile devices, especially on Ipad. Maybe because the html markup gets very large when inserting the cities options.. The problem with meme cache is storing it on memory, but I will give it a try. It still bothers me the fact that this is basically static data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend implementing it,  using the jquery chosen plugin [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
plugin that can be used to filter, results, but since you are getting such a big response you can incorporate a search filter functionality with ajax as shown here,  [Jquery Ajax-Chosen](https://rvieiraweb.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/jquery-ajax-chosen-simple-demo-tutorial/)